# Grant default privileges for specific database in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I have a database called `funnycode`. I also have a user called `funnycode_user`.

How do I grant default privileges to `funnycode_user` so that the user can:

1. Create a database under the name `funnycode`.
2. User can connect to any future database with the name `funnycode`, but not other databases.
3. User can select from all tables and has access to all sequences on any future database under the name `funnycode` but not other databases.

Is this possible in Postgres? If so, how? I [read the documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), but I don't see how this:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT INSERT ON TABLES TO funnycode_user;
```

Is tied to a specific database, in my case that would be the `funnycode` database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that creates a database automatically owns that database (unless a different owner is specified) and thus automatically has all privileges on the database. You don't need any additional grants to enable that user creating and using tables in the database.

So if you give `funnycode_user` the `create database` privilege, he can create **any** database he wants, not just `funnycode`. There is no way to prevent that.

Every new database that is created automatically grants the `connect` privilege to the role `public`. If you don't want `funnycode_user` to connect to other database, you need to revoke that privilege from the public role for every database.

Another way of limiting access to a specific database for a specific user, is through [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

You would need an entry like that:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER              ADDRESS        METHOD
host    funnycode       funnycode_user    0.0.0.0/0      md5
```

The entry `0.0.0.0/0` means that `funnycode_user` can connect from any IP address. Even if `funnycode_user` created other databases, he wouldn't be able to connect to them.

---

I think the better (cleaner) way is to **not** give that user the privilege to create database. Just create that database once, make `funnycode_user` the owner and that's it.

E.g. as the superuser run:

```
create user funnycode_user password 'VerySecret';
create database funnycode owner = funnycode_user;
```

You only need to do that once (or after funnycode_user decides to drop the database) and you don't need to give funnycode_user the privilege to create databases.

Comment: Just to clarify. You are saying that if I make `funnycode_user` the owner of a particular database, I do not need to then go and grant that user privileges for accessing the tables and the sequences? Because as an owner of the database, that user already has those privileges?